# I get an sqlite error code 1 whenever I try inputting data into my database (in android studio)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created a database helper class, and when I run the code I keep getting the following error message: "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table words_info has no column named back_word (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: INSERT INTO words_info(front_word,back_word) VALUES (?,?)." I tried changing the version of the database but that didn't work either...
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

```
package com.example.language;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelperDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "words.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "words_info";
    public static final String FRONT_WORD = "front_word";
    public static final String BACK_WORD = "back_word";




    public HelperDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String st = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + FRONT_WORD + " TEXT , " + BACK_WORD + "TEXT ) "; //CREATE TABLE words_info (front_word TEXT, back_word TEXT)
        db.execSQL(st);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addWord(Card c){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(FRONT_WORD, c.getFront_word());
        cv.put(BACK_WORD, c.getBack__word());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<Card> getWords(){
        List<Card> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            //loop through the cursor (result set) and create new card object. put them into the return list
            do{
                String front_word = cursor.getString(0);
                String back_word = cursor.getString(1);

                Card card = new Card(front_word, back_word);
                returnList.add(card);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else{

        }
        cursor.close();
        return returnList;
    }

    public void deleteOne(Card c){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String queryString = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + FRONT_WORD + " = " + c.getFront_word();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

    }


}
```

```
2022-05-01 16:15:56.733 2853-2853/com.example.language E/SQLiteLog: (1) table words_info has no column named back_word in "INSERT INTO words_info(front_word,back_word) VALUES (?,?)"
2022-05-01 16:15:56.737 2853-2853/com.example.language E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting front_word=hello back_word=hello
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table words_info has no column named back_word (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: INSERT INTO words_info(front_word,back_word) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:901)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:62)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:2217)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:2088)
        at com.example.language.HelperDB.addWord(HelperDB.java:51)
        at com.example.language.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a space in front of the second "TEXT"

so your code to create table will look like this:

```
String st = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + FRONT_WORD + " TEXT , " + BACK_WORD + " TEXT ) ";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error

Comment: @apeman delete the App and rerun. The onCreate method will only run once, that is when the database doesn't exist. So deleting the App will delete the database allowing onCreate to then run and thus create the table using the corrected SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well however I keep getting the same error message

Comment: @apeman, I agree with Ashish Mathur.  The code in your example will produce this query string `CREATE TABLE words_info ( front_word TEXT , back_wordTEXT )` so the error just means SQLite can't find the "back_word" column because it was accidentally named "back_wordTEXT".  Also, like MikeT said, if you're creating your database only when the application is first run, then to determine whether or not an attempted fix has worked, you'll need to uninstall your application from your test device and reinstall it with the fixed create query/code.